# Any closed-form solution to this integral (multivariate exponential)?

Tags: density-function, integral

Here is the probability density function (unnormalized) of a covariance matrix: (from a Bayesian perspective):

$$
f(\boldsymbol{V})\propto \det(\boldsymbol{V})^{-\frac{N+J+1}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{K}}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta})^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right]d\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $K \times 1$ vector,

$\boldsymbol{y}_i$ is a $J \times 1$ vector,

$\boldsymbol{X}_i$ is a $J \times K$ matrix,

$\boldsymbol{V}$ is a $J \times J$ covariance matrix, and

$N>K>J$. $\space \mathbb{R}^{K}$ is a $K$-dimensional real space.

The first $J$ columns of $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ are an identity matrix $\boldsymbol{I}_{J \times J}$. This is a multi-dimensional linear regression model.

My question is:

Is the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{K}}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta})^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right]d\boldsymbol{\beta}$ analytically computable when $\boldsymbol{V}$ is fixed? It seems like a multivariate exponential integral. When $K=J=1$, this is a non-standard univariate inverse chi-squared distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom, as proven in Gelman's *Bayesian Data Analysis* (third edition) pp. 64-66.

Comment: This is a standard multivariate Normal integral.

Comment: @whuber I tried it, but the fact that the integrated variable is $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ seems to make it difficult.

Comment: The sum is a sum of quadratic functions of $\beta$ and therefore is a quadratic function of $\beta.$  That means you can express it in the form $-\beta^\prime \Sigma \beta/2 + \tau^\prime \beta + u$ for some square symmetric matrix $\Sigma,$ vector $\tau,$ and number $u.$ In other words, it is a *Gaussian* function.  You know how to integrate those.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints by @whuber. Let me answer this question myself.

The quadratic term can be written as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta})^{\top}
\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta})
=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}
-2\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\top}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}^{\top}
\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}\right)
+\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\top}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}^{\top}
\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}\right)\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$

Let $\boldsymbol{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}$, $\boldsymbol{b}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{X}_{i}^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}$, $c=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}^{\top}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}_{i}$. Here, $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a $K \times K$ symmetric positive definite matrix, $\boldsymbol{b}$ is a $K\times 1$ vector, and $c$ is a scalar.

Now the integral term is

$$
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}c\right)\int_{\mathbb{R}^{K}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\top}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\beta}+
\boldsymbol{b}^{\top}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)d\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$

Applying the [Gaussian integral formula (n-dimensional with linear term)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization) from Wikipedia, the integral term is

$$
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}c\right)
\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{b}^{\top}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{b}\right)
\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^{K}}{\det(\boldsymbol{A})}}
$$